# Why do we see huge span in stock value in pre or post market on Yahoo! finance?

Tags: united-states, stocks

Looking at various stock (TSLA in the picture below on May 19, 2023) pre and post market trading graphs, I can nearly every day see some huge variations, way over market fluctuations, which I think do not make any sense (in the example below, we see back & forth jumps of +54.91% and -53.32%, even when we last saw TSLA taking a hit, it was not even -20% and it took a good hour to happen).

Looking at some other graphs (Google/Ameritrade/E*Trade), I do not see these variations making me think it's just a small glitch in the *Yahoo! Finance* display (although doing a reload doesn't fix anything, so the funky data would be on Yahoo!'s servers too).

So my question is: Should I ignore those extra-ordinary fluctuations? Or are these real (just too small to be shown on other services)?

---

The picture shows that the closing price was 180.14. After hours, it stayed pretty stable around 180.01 and 179.99. However, at 05:01 PM, as we can see on the left, the price jumped all the way to 278.84 and at 05:03 PM also down to $117.40. These numbers don't seem to make sense when the stock is currently traded at about $180. Why would someone sell at $117.40 when they could get an extra $63/share or buy at $278 when they could save nearly $100 buying that same stock?

[image]

Comment: The linked question is correct in general, but I think this example is just bad data. There's no way someone sold tesla for 117 when they could sell it for ~180 the next morning. My guess is the 117 and 278 should be 177 and 178, respectively.  In fact if I look at TSLA after hours now on Yahoo I do not see those spikes

Comment: @DStanley Yeah. That's how it feels like. I just tried a reload and I still see those huge ticks at 5:01 and 5:03. There is also one at 5:05. After that, it stayed around 180 for the rest of the post market.